# CSS column-count and position relative behavior in Chrome

Tags: html, css

If I use a position relative for an item which is inside column-count, it does not appear in **Chrome** (latest version).

In the following code, `.left` has the `position: relative` and it does not appear.

How can I make it work without removing the relative position property?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">                
    <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="left"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/E4rkDHN.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="right">luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

.box {
    width: 240px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: yellow;    
}

.left {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/eLmhedrt/

Comment: i think if you don't add `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` value in your css it acts like `postion` `static`

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `position: relative;` to `img`, like this:

```
img{
  position: relative;
}
```

You can also check it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/c7czLvxj/). I hope it helps you :)

Comment: you have removed `.left{ position: relative }` , but the OP has cited they need that property on `.left` class

Answer (score 1):

I just changed as following and now image is displaying

```
.left {
    position: relative;
    margin:2px ;
}
```